# Последние открытые файлы в RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

Подскажите как можно реализовать отображение последних открытых файлов в `RichTextBox`? Нужно чтобы эти файлы отображались в виде списка и можно было нажать на них и посмотреть. Пример на рисунке.

[image: Пример]

Answer (score 0):

Во первых, нужно где то сохранять адреса открытых файлов. Для этого можно использовать User Settings. Можно все организовать примерно так:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication6
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        Dictionary<string,string> docs;
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            docs = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            if (Properties.Settings.Default.DocsList != null)
                foreach (var rw in Properties.Settings.Default.DocsList)
                {
                    if (!docs.Select(r => r.Key).Contains(rw))
                        docs.Add(rw, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(rw));
                }
            dataGridView1.DataSource = docs.ToList();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (var dlg = new OpenFileDialog())
            {
                if(dlg.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    openDoc(dlg.FileName);
                }
            }
        }
        private void openDoc(string fileName)
        {
            if (Properties.Settings.Default.DocsList == null)
                Properties.Settings.Default.DocsList = new System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection();
            Properties.Settings.Default.DocsList.Add(fileName);
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
            richTextBox1.LoadFile(fileName);
            if (!docs.Select(r => r.Key).Contains(fileName))
            {
                docs.Add(fileName, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName));
                dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
                dataGridView1.DataSource = docs.ToList();
            }
        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            var f = dataGridView1[colKey.Name, dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Value;
            if (f != null)
                openDoc(f.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Нужно еще организовать удаление из списка.

Comment: А что такое DocsList и colKey? Выдает на них ошибку.

Comment: Зайдите Project => Properties и в секции Settings добавьте DocsList, Type System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection . colKey наименование колонки dataGridView1

Comment: Какой файл не попытаюсь открыть, то появляется ошибка в этих строчках - richTextBox1.LoadFile(fileName); if (!docs.Select(r => r.Key).Contains(fileName)). То недопустимый формат, хотя пробую и txt и rtf, то Значение не может быть неопределенным.

Comment: 1. richTextBox1.LoadFile может загрузить только rtf файлы; 2. Причину второй ошибки не знаю, посмотрите в дебаге значения переменных. Можете попробовать очистить DocsList, для этого добавьте буттон и на клик напишите следующее: ` Properties.Settings.Default.DocsList = null;
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();`

Comment: @Kaya _Какой файл не попытаюсь открыть, то появляется ошибка_ Для сохранения файла используйте комманду: `richTextBox1.SaveFile(fileName);` .Сохраненный таким образом файл откроется без проблем.