# Список последних открытых файлов

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, richtextbox

Делаю текстовый редактор. Как в `ListView` отобразить список последних открытых файлов в `RichTextBox`? Что-то вроде истории открытия файлов. Файлы открываются при помощи `Button` (код ниже).

```
private void buttonOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.Filter = "Rich Text Format | *.rtf";
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            richTextBox1.LoadFile(ofd.FileName);
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Прежде чем задавать вопрос, поищите. Точно такой же вопрос:  [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/677439/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D0%B2-richtextbox)